# Tools for heterogeneous systems and way to start MySQL cluster automatically

Tags: linux, automation, mysql-cluster, autoscaling

I'm trying to auto start of MySQL Cluster.

There are several nodes and several distinct processes, and I must start them in the proper order.

Firstly, I must start ndb_mgmd on management nodes, then I must be sure that it is working.
After that, I must run ndbmtd on data nodes, again ensuring that it's working. After, all usual mysql on MySQL servers.

For now, I have only 3 nodes (1 as management and MySQL and 2 as data nodes), and I can make my own little script. But if there are ever more servers and nodes, how I can do this?

Are there any tools for such problems? I know about chef and puppet for configuration. You can give different roles to different nodes, and they will be configured in right way. Can I take something (may be not these tools) and assign roles/configs to servers like "server of first type must run this process if all servers of second type are running process2"?

I'm not looking for things like scripts from SeveralNines, I want to know about general ways to solve such problems.

Comment: A cluster engine like Heartbeat or the Red Hat Cluster suite may help you. Chef can do limited orchestration when Chef clients connect to the Chef server to ask for details about other nodes. CFEngine Enterprise can also do this, but I think a proper cluster engine would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add this comment as an answer? (I can't set it as solution)
Now I'm reading documentation to find acceptible tool. Also there is Zookeeper, but I didn't sure that it does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cluster engine like Heartbeat or the Red Hat Cluster suite may help you. Chef can do limited orchestration when Chef clients connect to the Chef server to ask for details about other nodes. CFEngine Enterprise can also do this, but I think a proper cluster engine would be the way to go.